# Google Analytics Report API v4: get Sessions and Revenue data

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-reporting-api

I trying to get Sessions, Revenue, Transactions, Bounce Rate data from Google Analytics Report API v4 
with grouping by Chanel:

- Organic search
- Email
- Direct
- Branded Paid Search
- Social
- Referral
- .. etc

Right now I'm programming a Java module with test Request which has setted following parameters:

**Dimensions:**

ga:acquisitionTrafficChannel;

**Metrics:**

ga:sessions

ga:percentNewSessions

ga:newUsers

When I use `ga:acquisitionTrafficChannel + ga:sessions` GA Report api returns values, but when I try to add in request **ga:percentNewSessions, ga:newUsers**, it returns error:

```
{
  "domain": "global",
  "message": "Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together.",
  "reason": "badRequest"
}
```

To perform request in code I do following:

```
DateRange dateRange = new DateRange();
            dateRange.setStartDate("2015-06-15");
            dateRange.setEndDate("2015-06-30");
            ReportRequest request = new ReportRequest()
                    .setViewId(context.getProperty(VIEW_ID).evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue())
                    .setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(dateRange))
                    .setDimensions(Arrays.asList(
                            new Dimension().setName("ga:acquisitionTrafficChannel")
                    ))
                    .setMetrics(Arrays.asList(
                            new Metric().setExpression("ga:sessions"),
                            new Metric().setExpression("ga:percentNewSessions"),
                            new Metric().setExpression("ga:newUsers")
                    ));

            ArrayList<ReportRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();
            requests.add(request);
            GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest().setReportRequests(requests);
            GetReportsResponse response = service.reports().batchGet(getReport).execute();
```

How to do request correctly? Is in the right direction do I go?

Because as I said, I will need to do same thing with Revenue, Bounce Rate.. 
but I not fully understand how to combine Metrics and Dimensions without errors.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I've tried out the combinations you provided in the [Dimensions and Metrics Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#mode=api) and it shows that these metrics (all four together) could be used all at once (unless I'm reading this the wrong way). Could you provide more details as to how you're sending the request?

Comment: AL, accordingly to your question I updated post. As you noted Dimensions and Metrics Explorer shows that combination of that metrics can be used.. When I use just "ga:sessions" it works ok

Answer (score 2):

About my question:

As solution for my needs I used following combination in code:

To get all Channel groups ("Organic Search, Email, Direct, etc") I used following dimension:
`ga:channelGrouping` - it will return all

To get values for Sessions, Revenue, Transactions, Bounce Rate, etc I used following metrics:

```
ga:sessions
ga:transactionRevenue
ga:transactions
ga:bounceRate
```

Also here can be more metrics if it is needed.

Maybe it will be useful to somebody.

Actually, question about error with combination in question (with `ga:acquisitionTrafficChannel`) is still open :)